# Get Credentials from different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create project and following is scenario :

**Database tables:**

```
Table first : Company
Table Second :Employee
```

when superuser create company then i put information in company table like company name, user name and password.
Then with these username and password company login and enter its employee like name, gender , phone no etc plus username and password for employee so that employee can login as well with its employee rights.

confusion is that when superadmin create new company then it enter values in company table and when company create emplyee account then i enter value in employee table. So on login screen how i can check its superadmin, company or employee so that i can get information from that perticular database table.

Can you guys help me to create database for this scenario. how i can manage what should i use join , view or.....

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is correct as you're putting relevant information in each table. *E.g. Company's data in company table and Employee's data in employee table.*

What you need to do is when someone logins from platform add a extra parameter along with credentials for the type of user.

There are couple of solutions for this,

1. Create two separate pages for Employee and Company's login.
2. Have single login page for both of the user having selection box for the user type.

Comment: Thanks for reply! is there any another way that i can create join  for company and employe and in view i get username and password and check in both table  for login. rather then to give selection box. if yes any idea how i can implement it

Comment: Yes you can join but that will fail in case of same email id/username in both the table.s. So it's better and good practice to query both tables differently based on user type.

Comment: select tbl_employee.employee_username as EmpUsername, tbl_company.company_username as comUsername ,tbl_employee.employee_Passord,  tbl_company.company_password from tbl_employee  INNER JOIN tbl_comapany ON tbl_company.company_id =tbb_employee.company_id;        some thing like this. may be?

Comment: That won't solve the purpose, In above query you don't know the credentials of the company or a employee.

Comment: tbl_employee.employee_username as EmpUsername, tbl_employee.employee_Passord,tbl_company.company_Username,tbl_company.company_password   I got user name and password for both company and employee but company data get repeated in result

Comment: Do like I've mentioned, passing user type and querying only related table.